# Django "Error: cannot import name escape" on windows

Tags: windows, django, development-environment

I cannot run the dev server because of this error ("Error: cannot import name escape").

I assume its because of modifications I've done to the project, but i have no idea how to find where the error is originating from to fix it.

I don't import anything called escape anywhere.

#### Update

Using django-admin.py rather than the projects manage.py, don't know why...

#### Update 2

Now manage.py is working. This may be because I had a file called email.py which was trying to import email.mime.text (ie trying to import itself) renaming to sendemail.py solved this problem.

Comment: what version of Django are you running?  Did you recently upgrade versions, or are you using any 3rd party apps?

Comment: Latest 1.1.1, nope, just whats included in python/django

Comment: Full traceback? (`--traceback`)

Comment: Didn't know about traceback thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it was your email.py.  Deleting it will fix your problem.  This is not a Windows specific problem as I had the same problem on Ubuntu.

You can duplicate this error by doing "touch email.py" or using a text editor to create an empty email.py file.

I had this same problem and your notes tipped me off.  It seemed to start occurring out of nowhere.  I have several pointless .py files sitting around and one of them was named email.py.  It was not trying to import itself or anything.  I only named it email because I was planning on emailing it to someone.  I got rid of it (and the .pyc) and now everything works.  I don't know what is special about email.py, but that was indeed the problem.